# How to redirect page and show message when php error on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, handle

I want to redirect a page and then show a message when a php error show on codeigniter, how to do that ?

here my php **error** example

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Error
>       Message: Call to a member function GetToken() on null
>       Filename: operator_pt/Profil_operatorpt.php
>       Line Number: 95 
>       Backtrace:

Edit : Request from kuldep
here my code from controller

```
public function testkoneksi()
    {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('url','URL','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('category_success', 'ISI DATA DENGAN BENAR.');
            redirect('operator_pt/profil_operatorpt', 'refresh');   

        }
        else
        {

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library("Nusoap_lib");
        $url = $_POST["url"];
        //$url = 'http://localhost:8082/ws/live.php?wsdl';

        $client = new nusoap_client($url, true);

        $proxy = $client->getproxy();

        //mendapatkan token

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $url = $_POST["url"];
        $result=$proxy->GetToken($username, $password);
        $token = $result;
        if (isset($token)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('token_sukses', 'KONEKSI DENGAN FEEDER TELAH SUKSES.');
                redirect('operator_pt/profil_operatorpt', 'refresh');   
}
else $this->session->set_flashdata('token_gagal', 'KONEKSI DENGAN FEEDER GAGAL, CEK ULANG USERNAME, PASSWORD & URL-NYA.');
                redirect('operator_pt/profil_operatorpt', 'refresh');       
    }
}
```

Comment: you are calling GetToken() on an object which is null

Comment: i know that. The point is I want to redirect this error page and show a message. Because it's a part of some validation.

Comment: please show your php code.....

Comment: @kuldeep it's complicated. I want to validate an url variable from nusoap if it's really connected to web service. But no matter what I do I can't do that. it's always show that error page when the variable is wrong. So the only way to validate this variable is to redirect this error page and show some message that variable is wrong ..

Comment: Profil_operatorpt.php  file code show ............

Comment: @kuldeep check my post again, the point is if I insert wrong $URL, I can't connect to nusoap web server, and show php error like that. I want to create a check connection function ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Error', 'redirect' => base_url() . 'Path to redirect');
            header('Content-Type:application/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
```

This may work. Give your error message in place of 'Error'.

Comment: where I should put this code ? on controller or view ?

Comment: On controller when your function is about to finish.